# Custom Wordpress template with custom category loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a salesperson page template in wordpress.  Each page will have salesperson bio, contact and image.  All of this I can do.  What I also want is a section that queries the products that each salesperson sells.  The problem I'm running into is, not every salesperson sells the same products, so I can't have a standard loop that queries `x` category that I create.

To solve the problem, I figured I could give each product (which is a custom post type in the theme) a category that is unique to the salesperson so the template would have a loop that would loop through products with `jim-products` category for jim the salesperson and products with `sally-products` category would be looped through for Sally the salesperson.

What I would like to avoid is making a new template for each category if I could.  I'm familiar with conditional formatting, and was thinking I could somehow do

```
if(in_category("sally-products"){
    "cat"=> 11 //jim's cat
}elseif(in_category("jim-products"){
    "cat"=4 //sally's cat
}
```

but I can't really get a point where that would help in this situation.  And even further, if there was a way to somehow have the client create a category for x salesperson and then apply the category to the page that would be even better.

Hopefully, this makes sense.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a bit too complicated to me. If you create a `category.php` template, you can display all products of a particular category in your example on one page using  `www.example.com/category/sally-products/` and similar addresses (different last part/category name for the other salespersons).

In the `category.php` template you can use a condition by category name and derive the salesperson name from that if you need it. That should work, I suppose.

Addition: If you also use categories for other purposes and don't want the generic category template to contain this content, you could create a custom taxonomy and use this in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, I’d need to make a separate template for each sales person then?  So if I have 10 sales people they would all get a different category template, that only has a different category arg but everything else is the same?

Comment: No, I am saying exactly the opposite: ONE `category.php` template

Comment: But how would I apply the unique salesperson data to that?  I need unique photos and text for each category.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know how many salespersons you have, but if it's only a few, you could put their data into conditions: If categoryname is sally-products echo sallyimage and sallytext, same for the others. If there are a lot of salespersons, better a custom page type for the salesperson data (as custom data fields) and a second loop in the same page fetching the products by category "xxx-products"

Answer (score 0):

After talking to  Johannes (thank you!), I came to an OK solution, although it is not exactly what I wanted.  If there is a way to get me where I originally wanted to get feel free to add another answer.

What I did in writing:

1. I made a custom post type called `Employee Bios`.

   - in sales rep I included all of the information for each sales rep: photo, bio, etc.
2. I created a custom template file `single-employee_bios.php`.

   - at the top of this template I formatted all of the information in `Sales Reps`.
3. after all of the information at the top, and after reseting the post data, I ran a separate `WP_query` that includes an if statement says if is page xxx, query category x.
4. Then I created a separate category for each employee and applied a the respective categories to each product that I wanted to be displayed on the respective employee bio page.

My custom query looks like this:

```
    <?php

        if($post->ID == 1613){
           $args = array(
              "cat"=> 19 //a category set on 
           );
        }else{
            $args = array(
          "cat"=> 18
        );
        }
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
        //Do Stuff here.....

    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
    // no posts found
    }
     ?>
```

Hopefully that makes sense.